# How can I split my screen to two separate window?

Tags: 18.04

I used `super` + `left arrow` / `right arrow` to do this before, but as I uninstalled my ubuntu and install it again, this combination does'nt work for every app! for example I can do this with document viewr with some pdf's but I cant do this with some different pdf's! 
I mean I'm really confused about it and I couldt find anything about this problem on web!
I would be appreciated if you help!

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to split your screen in terminal you should use tmux, you just have to type `tmux` and then `ctrl-b %` to split it horizantally, if you wanted to split it vertically then type `ctrl-b "`
i hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The GNOME Extension ShellTile will do this for you in 18.04

Install GNOME shell extensions (if not already done) and select ShellTile extension.

[image]

If you don't have GNOME extensions installed, [this link](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/) provides a good guide to follow.